unknown transport error on SocketIO with a Java project
When I search for "http://localhost:21687" or "http://localhost:21687/spdnet" at https://piehost.com/socketio-tester I get unknown transport for request /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=P08BSxo  ("polling&t=P08BSxo" part is changing sometimes) error in my terminal and I can never connect to SocketIO.
https://github.com/Not-Name-Dev-Team/SPDNetServer I downloaded this project, run ./gradlew, run gradle build, then run java -jar build/libs/SPDNetServer-0.0.1.jar. spring boot works, I get information that SocketIO is running on port 21687. I tried gradle versions 8.6 and 8.7 but the result did not change. Since chatGPT said so, I added “config.setTransports(Transport.WEBSOCKET, Transport.POLLING);” to the file in the path src\main\java\me\catand\spdnetserver\SocketService.java but nothing changed. The project is using "com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:2.0.8". The thing that I'm trying to do is running a server for a game (https://github.com/Not-Name-Dev-Team/New-SPDNet). I also consulted the project owner, but he stated that he has never encountered such an error.
The file content (src\main\java\me\catand\spdnetserver\SocketService.java) that I think provides the hosting of SocketIO is as follows:
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("0.0.0.0");
        config.setPort(21687);

        instance = this;
        server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        spdNetNamespace = server.addNamespace("/spdnet");
        if (seeds.isEmpty()) {
            seeds.put("seedFUN", getNoonTimestamp());
        }
        server.start();
        startAll();
        sender = new Sender(server);
        handler = new Handler(playerRepository, gameRecordRepository, this, sender, playerMap);
    }


You may want to look at requests/responses in your browser devtool panel.
